# if boolean == false syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, syntax, boolean

I can't get the following syntax to work:

```
if document.anonymous == false ?
```

I get this error: " syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' "

Here is the corresponding field for "anonymous" in the document model

```
field :anonymous, type: Boolean, default: true
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That question mark is not a part of Ruby syntax. `if x == false` is stylistically bad (`if !x` or `unless x` are normal), but should work; but the question mark kills it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `unless document.anonymous` in stead of `if document.anonymous == false ?`

Answer (score 1):

There should not be question mark. Use this

```
if document.anonymous == false
```

Answer (score 1):

either use

```
if document.anonymous == false #OR unless document.anonymous

else

end
```

OR

```
document.anonymous == false ? () : ()
```

Note:- In Ruby only false and nil are falsey. Ref [this](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking at this now, for booleans you can simply use:

`document.anonymous?` - returns `true` for boolean with value 1

`!document.anonymous?` - returns `true` for boolean with value 0